# Can we refer the other repository module in maven using other repository absolute path

Tags: java, maven-3

My project structure is like

```
repository -A
|-parent pom.xml
|
|--module 1
|--module 2
```

another

```
repository -B
|-parent pom.xml
```

due to some design decision one of the module is maintained separately in another repository(repository B) so now
while building A i want to do the build of B first.

I have checked the aggregation function but it needs that B & A should have same parent C and i need to triggered `mvn -install` on C's `pom.xml`.

I have tried the 
repo A
`<module> ../local_path_to_repo_B pom</module>`  - this is working fine on local but while doing remote build it is failing due file path.

Is it possible to provide absolute repo path in module tag.
Or any other better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have done restructuring of my project and now both project are independent but are under a single POM. Now it is working fine.